# Do I need to 'burn out' the LP in the gas lines prior to swapping out an appliance?

Tags: gas, propane

I need to replace the flexpipe between my steel pipe and the propane insert. The one installed is too short.

Alas, there wasn't a shut-off installed at the fireplace, so I needed to shut off the LP from the tank outside.

I figured before I unhook anything, I should try and burn out the LP in the line via the gas range.

Question 1: Is that a necessary step? Seems that's safer than letting what propane is in the piles leak out into the room as I decouple the connections.

Question 2: How long should it take to burn out what's left in the line? I've been running the burners for about 10 minutes now. The flame has gone down, but it's still going (there's maybe 40' of pipe between tank outside and range).

(PS, I *will* be installing a proper shut off valve as I replace the flex pipe to avoid this in the future.)

Comment: I wouldn't expect that much gas to be in the line, not to mention the fact that there should be no (or very low) pressure in the line if it's shut off. Are you sure the shutoff is fully closed? I would expect the flame to die very quickly after the valve is off, especially since the orifice on a range burner is quite large.

Comment: @Tester101 I think what happened is we have an 'iffy' valve on the tank. Turning it back on all the way and then back off again fixed it. Maybe it hadn't been turned in a while and just needed some coaxing? Either way, I'm going to have the propane company look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no.  the problem you find will be the odor of the gas, not the fire risk.  Just air the room a little, you'll be good.  keep the candles for the next day.
Good idea put in a valve for next time.